# Как вывести определённое количество ссылок в постраничной навигации

Tags: php, mysql

Я новичек в программировании.
Подскажите пожалуйста как можно задать условие для вывода постраничной навигации чтоб отображалось первые 15 странниц ссылок потом троеточие и последние 10. При нажатии на 15, будет отображаться 16 и т.д.
Спасибо.

button.class.php

```
<?php

class Button
{
    public $page;
    public $text;
    public $isActive;

    public function __construct($page, $isActive = true, $text = null)
    {
        $this->page = $page;
        $this->text = is_null($text) ? $page : $text;
        $this->isActive = $isActive;
    }

    public function activate()
    {
        $this->isActive = true;
    }

    public function deactivate()
    {
        $this->isActive = false;
    }
}
```

pagination.class.php

```
class Pagination
{
     public $buttons = array()

     public function __construct(Array $options = array('itemsCount' => 257, 'itemsPerPage' => 10, 'currentPage' => 1))
        {
            extract($options);


            if (!$currentPage) {
                return;
            }

            /** @var int $pagesCount
             *  @var int $itemsCount
             *  @var int $itemsPerPage
             */
            $pagesCount = ceil($itemsCount / $itemsPerPage);

            if ($pagesCount == 1) {
                return;
            }

            /** @var int $currentPage */
            if ($currentPage > $pagesCount) {
                $currentPage = $pagesCount;
            }

            $this->buttons[] = new Button($currentPage - 1, $currentPage > 1, 'Previous');

            for ($i = 1; $i <= $pagesCount; $i++) {
                if ($i > 15) {
                    break;
                }
                $active = $currentPage != $i;
                $this->buttons[] = new Button($i, $active);
            }

            $this->buttons[] = new Button($currentPage + 1, $currentPage < $pagesCount, 'Next');
        }
    }
```

index.php

```
<?php $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? (int)$_GET['page'] : 1;

$p = new Pagination(array(
    'itemsCount' => $data['count'][0]['cnt'],
'itemsPerPage' => 10,
'currentPage' => $page
));

?>


    <div align="center">
        <?php foreach ($p->buttons as $button) :
        if ($button->isActive) : ?>
        <a href = '?page=<?=$button->page?>'><?=$button->text?></a>
        <?php else : ?>
        <span style="color:#555555"><?=$button->text?></span>
        <?php endif;
    endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Примерно так хотелось бы чтоб было :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вопрос не совсем понятен , у вас есть пример?

Comment: `extract()` - плохо, не понятно откуда и какиэ переменные берутся.